# pyparsing fails to find a complete parse in presence of an ambiguous grammar?

Tags: pyparsing

I am trying to apply `pyparsing` to solve the [Advent of Code 2015 Day 19](https://adventofcode.com/2015/day/19) puzzle.

The simplest example shows an ambiguous grammar `e => H; e => O; H => HO; H => OH; O => HH` and seeks the number of replacements to parse `HOH` from the start symbol `e`.  One such solution is `e -> O -> HH -> HOH`.

I attempted the following (which doesn't yet count the number of replacements):

```
  import pyparsing as pp
  pp.ParserElement.enable_left_recursion()

  sym_H = pp.Forward()
  sym_O = pp.Forward()

  sym_e = sym_H ^ sym_O
  sym_H <<= (sym_H + sym_O) ^ (sym_O + sym_H) ^ 'H'
  sym_O <<= (sym_H + sym_H) ^ 'O'

  # This should parse the entire string using e -> O -> HH -> HOH  but fails?
  print(sym_e.parse_string('HOH'))  # Shows: ['H', 'O'].
```

This code uses the `Or` (`^`) operator rather than the usual `MatchFirst` (`|`) because the documentation explains that it should find a longest possible match.

Is there intuition for why `parse_string` cannot find a (non-unique) expansion that matches the full string?  Is there perhaps a simple code modification to make it work?

Someone [successfully used CYK parsing on this puzzle](https://www.reddit.com/r/adventofcode/comments/3xflz8/comment/cy4ds8a/); is that parsing algorithm more general (but slower) than the one in `pyparsing`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem, and it touches on a feature in pyparsing that is still relatively new to me, the support for left-recursion.

I made some essentially cosmetic changes to your grammar, to set up support for naming the elements, which helps in diagramming and debugging.

```py
O = pp.Literal("O")
H = pp.Literal("H")
sym_e = sym_H ^ sym_O
sym_H <<= (sym_H + sym_O) ^ (sym_O + sym_H) ^ H
sym_O <<= (sym_H + sym_H) ^ O
```

Then adding these two lines defines names for all the expression variables, and sets the debug flag for them.

```py
pp.enable_diag(
    pp.Diagnostics.enable_debug_on_named_expressions
)
pp.autoname_elements()
```

Before running to get the debug output, I also called create_diagram() to see if there were any insights that might give:

[image: parser railroad diagram]

The debug output shows the progressive attempts at parsing the individual sub-expressions, and ending with:

```
[... much output clipped ...]
Match sym_O at loc 0(1,1)
  HOH
  ^
Match sym_O failed, ParseException raised: Forward recursion without base case, found 'HOH'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
Match H at loc 0(1,1)
  HOH
  ^
Matched H -> ['H']
Match H at loc 0(1,1)
  HOH
  ^
Matched H -> ['H']
Matched sym_H -> ['H', 'O']
Matched sym_e -> ['H', 'O']
['H', 'O']
```

On a hunch, I reversed the order of the two expressions for `sym_e`:

```py
sym_e = sym_O ^ sym_H
```

And this time, the debug output ended with:

```
[... much output clipped ...]
Match O failed, ParseException raised: Expected O, found 'HOH'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
Match sym_H at loc 0(1,1)
  HOH
  ^
Matched sym_H -> ['H', 'O']
Match sym_H at loc 2(1,3)
  HOH
    ^
Matched sym_H -> ['H']
Matched sym_O -> ['H', 'O', 'H']
Matched sym_e -> ['H', 'O', 'H']
['H', 'O', 'H']
```

A successful match!

So I think the left-recursion logic may have issues in the face of expressions using the '^' operator, that it might be giving up a little too soon. Or that it is not smart enough to undo an initial `sym_H` match of the leading "HO" leaving the trailing H unparsed, to back up and choose a shorter `sym_H` match of the leading "H", so that the following "OH" would match the second `sym_H` needed for a matched `sym_O`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and the nice visualization and debugging tools.  The docs explain `“bounded recursion” parsing, which allows for both direct and indirect left-recursion. During parsing, left-recursive Forward elements are repeatedly matched with a fixed recursion depth that is gradually increased until finding the longest match.`  So the fact that the recursion depth is only lazily increased might be causing the search to miss the deeper, longer expansion.  I'm also just guessing here.